Enter u-boot on Speedport Plus
So I have Sagemcom Speedport Plus which is based on SoC: Lantiq GRX389 v1.1 and SoC: xRX330 rev 1.1 and the problem is that I cant enter u-boot. Here is boot log, any idea on what I need to enter when it says nmc: waiting 5 seconds for command ?
